# Asus G73gj Fan runs full speed all the time.

Tags: overheating, fan, fancontrol

I have an Asus G73jh, I'm not sure what BIOS version I have but my laptop seems to have the fans running full speed all the time. I installed lmsensors and my laptop is normally around 56C (which is allot cooler than it used to run at 76c before I switched to Ubuntu). My question is, do I need to change something in the BIOS? or is there a program for 14.04 to control fan speeds? When I ran sensorsdetect I only saw the cpu listed. Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have already configured lmsensors by running `sudo sensors-detect` answering yes to insert detected modules into `/etc/modules`

Now load your modules, install and configure fancontrol:

```
sudo start kmod  
sudo apt-get install fancontrol
sudo pwmconfig
```

Set your interval to something between 1 and 4 seconds when running pwmconfig. Run: `sudo service fancontrol start`

Comment: I get this error when doing sudo pwmconfig /usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed

Comment: `cat /etc/modules` run `sudo modprobe driver` exchanging _driver_ for what ever the /etc/modules file indicate lmsensors added during the sensors-detect before you try again. Rebooting the computer is another alternative. On my Intel Core 2 system, the needed modules are coretemp and it87.

Comment: #----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

This is the result I get from sensors detect. How do I see if I have the right modules?

Comment: If `cat /etc/modules | grep coretemp` returns coretemp and only coretemp, then it is already added to /etc/modules, which will make it load during boot. `sudo -s` (continue as superuser) `echo coretemp >> /etc/modules` will add it to your /etc/modules file. You can probe it with `sudo modprobe coretemp` which will eliminate the need to reboot. `lsmod | grep coretemp` returning any line starting with coretemp will tell you if it is already loaded.

Comment: joe@joe-G73Jh:~$ cat /etc/modules | grep coretemp
coretemp
coretemp
joe@joe-G73Jh:~$ echo coretemp >> /etc/modules
bash: /etc/modules: Permission denied
joe@joe-G73Jh:~$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for joe: 
root@joe-G73Jh:~# echo coretemp >> /etc/modules
root@joe-G73Jh:~# sudo modprobe coretemp
root@joe-G73Jh:~# lsmod | grep coretemp
coretemp               13435  0 
root@joe-G73Jh:~#

So it sounds like it is loaded but I didnt see the cpu module there.